# multiple selectors in jquery as AND

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a quite simple question.

On jquery, a multiple selection, lets say $(".class1, #id2") select the elements as an "or" operator, since it will select all elemets with .class1 and all elements with #id2.

However, is there a way to make the selection an an "and" operator? in the example all elements that have both, class1 and id2 will be selected, but if it has only class1 or only id2, they must not be selected.

I know that only one element can have id2, however this is a general question, you can change id2 for anything you want, for example data-id

Comment: If there is no space or comma between the selector elements, then they are required to both be present on the same object as in `#id2.class1`.  jQuery uses the same rules as CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $("#id2.class1") // selects an element with id of 'id2' and class of 'class1'
```

or by using `Attribute Equals` selector:

```
 $(".class1[id='id2']")
```

Answer (score 4):

Just chain the selectors:

```
$('#id2.class1')
```

Same as in CSS. From the [CSS selector specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html):

> A *simple selector* is either a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#type-selectors) or [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector) followed immediately by zero or more [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors), [ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#id-selectors), or [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes), in any order. The simple selector matches if all of its components match.

You might wonder that you are neither using a type selector nor the universal selector, but the universal selector is implicit here. Thus, `#id2` is the same as `*#id2`.

Also you might notice that the class selector is not mentioned here, but I think that's only because it is a language specific selector (HTML) and is equivalent to `[class~="class1"]`.

So, you can simply can combine ID selectors, class selectors, attribute selectors and pseudo-class selectors in any order you want and they can optionally be preceded with a type selector.

Some examples:

```
p.foo
a[rel=follow]
#foo.bar.baz[data-id=42]:hover
```

The last one is equivalent to

```
.baz.bar:hover[data-id=42]#foo
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know that only one element can have id2, however this is a general
>   question, you can change id2 for anything you want, for example
>   data-id

There is a huge difference in id and data-id and the syntax for the answer to your question would be completely different.

Using an id and a class either get none or 1 element at most (as you should have unique ids) making the "and" a little redundant.

```
$("#myDiv.myClass") // Should in theory only return a single element
```

However if you query for elements with the same data-id and class you can get multiple elements back.

Looking for common attribute and class value could look like this:

```
$(".myClass[data-id='myDiv']")​; // Can return multiple elements
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/6DtZ6/)